# Polymer input-header element does not have the expected behavior

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I followed the steps in the following video
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDjiUmx51y8
and created my custom input-header Polymer element as below

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="input-header">

  <template>

    <style>
      .dropdown-content {
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>

    <paper-toolbar>

      <paper-icon-button icon="mail"></paper-icon-button>

      <div class="title">{{label}}</div>

      <paper-menu-button horizontal-align="right" vertical-align="top">
        <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <paper-input label="Thread name:" value="{{label}}"></paper-input>
        </div>
      </paper-menu-button>
    </paper-toolbar>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'input-header',

      properties: {

        label: {
          type: String,
          notify: true
        }

      }

    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Then I called it in my index.html as follows

```
      <input-header label="{{label}}"></input-header>
```

But I am not getting the behavior shown in the video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDjiUmx51y8

where the input field appears when he clicks on the menu button.

Infact, nothing happens when I click on the menu button.

I am using the 1.2.1 version of polymer so I think I am on the latest version.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What position in the video?

Comment: At 24:25 https://youtu.be/ZDjiUmx51y8?t=24m25s

Comment: I get the effect (ported your example code to Dart Polymer), just the styling (size) is broken. Maybe you're just missing the imports for the elements (paper-xxx, iron-icons) elements you're using.

Comment: What style did you add and where?

Comment: Just that from the code in your question, same place. I just copied your HTML. Just the JS code part looks different because I use Dart and I had to add the imports for the elements.

Comment: Thanks. You were right. I was missing the imports for the paper-input and other paper elements. I had another question. When I try to focus on the paper-input with my mouse by clicking on it, the paper-menu closes the div containing the paper-input. When I tab over the to the paper-input, it works ok and gets focus and I am able to type on the paper-input. Is there a way to prevent the div from hiding when I click on the paper-input to give it focus with my mouse pointer.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

As @GunterZochbauer pointed out, this was fixed by importing the paper elements in elements.html used in the input-header as follows

```
<!-- Paper elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-menu-button/paper-menu-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-scroll-header-panel/paper-scroll-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles-classes.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
```